# Fruit trees root growth

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, tree-care, growth, grafting

I have several fruit trees all in good condition, all around 2 years old.

One of them is a morello cherry. He was bought as a one year
Old.

On its second year, I missed pruning and ultimately he grew dozens of tiny branches all the way up the main stem which I have now trimmed, only leaving 4-5 buds to allow it to grow in a goblet shape which is working well. The main stem of the tree is also very strong and well established.

However,

This tree, for reasons unknown to me keeps growing new stems from the roots. I know all trees will try that and the others do as well but in a quantity which is nothing compared to this one. If I let it, I probably would end up with 2 main stems!!
I have tried to increase the compost around it to deprive the roots of light. Adding a bigger layer of mulch as well. 
All trees are fed regularly, all healthy. I do not use chemicals, it's all 100% organic tree care.  I live in Gloucestershire UK

I am stumped with this one. Any ideas?

Edit:
It was planted dormant in the
Ground  2 years ago February time with one year "wasted" with lack of pruning(as explained above) [image]The variety is as per comment.

Comment: Is it in a pot or the ground? Is it a patio cherry tree? Any chance of a photo?

Comment: Remember that I lost a year of growth, above ground not under ground. The whole of that stem was covered in leaves the first summer of planting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the new shoots are vigorous and come from the grafting point or from below the grafting point, it means that the new shoots are from the rootstock, not the same as the scion. This may be due to soil, leaves, mulch or anything that retains humidity that had stayed in contact with the grafting point during the growth season. This is also one of the reasons why, when planting a grafted tree, the grafting point is supposed to be a few centimeters above ground.

If you worry that a tree might need protection in winter, cover the grafting point after the tree has gone dormant and remove the protection when the tree breaks dormancy.

Update: Remove the suckers as soon as possible because they take away nutrients that should go to the upper tree (scion). Cut the suckers close to the trunk, the closer the better, and don't leave stubs because new suckers will appear on them.

Yes, remove the soil until the grafting point is a few inches above ground and keep it that way.

Comment: Ok. So should I unearth it and let it grow until its dormant then cut it as you would prune a branch?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.